# How to unstuck NPC in A Clash of Kings - M&B Warband Mod

Tags: mods, mount-and-blade-warband

Recently, I asked Tywin Lannister to help me besiege Duskendale and he really did it. Unfortunately, he's still inside the castle and doesn't even want to patrol or to do anything. If I want to give him some course of action he said he can't and still sitting in the castle. He do not leave the castle even when King's Landing was under siege. What should I do if I want him to act like a normal NPC I mean moving, attacking, patroling etc. etc. ? Thanks for answers :D